# equaling the PHP argument and mysql data makes foreach loop not work

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, quotes

When I'm doing this foreach loop perfectly works.

```
<?php
function checkInDB($NIC){
$user='root';
$pass='123';
$db='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recruit';
$dbh= new PDO($db,$user,$pass);

$sql = 'SELECT FirstName 
         FROM cv 
           JOIN candidate ON cv.cvID=candidate.cvID 
         WHERE ((submittedDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 365 day) 
           AND (candidate.NIC="906548765V"))';

echo '<h3>candidates</h3>', '<hr />', PHP_EOL;
echo '<table border=1>', PHP_EOL;
foreach ($dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

    echo '<tr><td>', implode('</td><td>', $row), '</td></tr>', PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>', PHP_EOL;
}
checkInDB("906548765V");

?>
```

but when I just changing `(candidate.NIC="906548765V")` to `(candidate.NIC=$NIC)` 
which even makes `echo ($NIC==="906548765V");`  true, throws an unexpected error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What exactly is happening there?

Comment: That is because your string `$sql` is constructed with single quotes and single quote does not interpret variables (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP there are 2 kind ways to define a string:

- Double quotes
- Single quotes

When you use Single quotes, the string will be as defined.
When using double quotes, PHP will parse the string.

Then on another note. Never ever include a variable into a query string. Just don't. SQL injection and all that. ALWAYS use prepared statements. You are using PDO, so it's easy:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT cols FROM table WHERE col1 = :myCol1Value');
$stmt->bindParam('myCol1Value',$theActualValue);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I'm a complete beginner to PHP.So,the problem is not even near in the area I thought as foreach loop! useful suggestion as well.

Comment: True, query does not return an array

Answer (score 0):

try `AND (candidate.NIC="'.$NIC.'")` since it's a string you still need the quotes.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted... It is a valid answer (though it is better to use single-quotes than doubles quotes in MySQL), however Pinoniq is more correct for the best way to do this.

Comment: That's not much of an answer, you should explain why this would solve the problem.